# iOS6 and automatic view unloading

Tags: iphone, ios, memory-management, uiviewcontroller, ios6

**Update:**
To clarify the context of the question; the question is not on how to avoid the problem, but to clarify what the piece of documentation means, as my experiment suggests that the views I was expecting to unload, based on the documentation, are not unloading. I would like to understand if this is a bug, or if I am misunderstanding the documentation. To solve the problem instead, I know that setting the images in viewWillAppear instead of viewDidLoad, and setting the images to nil in viewDidDisappear, is releasing the memory and the app doesn't crash. However, I would like to understand if the memory should have been released with the initial code, as the experiment is to simulate having such view controllers as outlets, and setting your UI images (backgrounds...) in Interface Builder, instead of setting them in code in viewWillAppear... 


**Original:**
I am trying to understand some new aspect of iOS6, as documented in the View Controller Programming Guide:

> On iOS 6 and Later, a View Controller Unloads Its Own Views When Desired
>   The default behavior for a view controller is to load its view hierarchy when the view property is first accessed and thereafter keep it in memory until the view controller is disposed of. The memory used by a view to draw itself onscreen is potentially quite large. However, the system automatically releases these expensive resources when the view is not attached to a window. The remaining memory used by most views is small enough that it is not worth it for the system to automatically purge and recreate the view hierarchy.

Let's say I am creating a simple app, with a rootViewController.
This rootViewController has a few child View Controllers, all declared as IBOutlets instead of being allocated in code.

```
@property(nonatomic,strong) IBOutlet ChildViewController *childViewController1;
@property(nonatomic,strong) IBOutlet ChildViewController *childViewController2;
@property(nonatomic,strong) IBOutlet ChildViewController *childViewController3;
@property(nonatomic,strong) IBOutlet ChildViewController *childViewController4;
@property(nonatomic,strong) IBOutlet ChildViewController *childViewController6;
@property(nonatomic,strong) IBOutlet ChildViewController *childViewController7;
@property(nonatomic,strong) IBOutlet ChildViewController *childViewController8;
@property(nonatomic,strong) IBOutlet ChildViewController *childViewController9;
@property(nonatomic,strong) IBOutlet ChildViewController *childViewController10;
```

The rootViewController has a few buttons, pressing each of those does a simple presentModalViewController operation on each childViewController

```
-(IBAction)showChild1Action:(id)sender{
  [self presentModalViewController:self.childViewController1 animated:true];
}
```

Each childViewController has a close button that dismisses the child view controller.

```
-(IBAction)closeAction:(id)sender{
  [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:true];
}
```

My expectation from the documentation was that the child view controller view objects would be released from memory, as the child view controllers are dismissed.
However I purposely tested with large view objects, and running profile on such an app, the memory usage just keeps growing as each child controller gets presented, and the app eventually crashes after I present child controller #7 or so.

What is your understanding of what has changed in iOS6 in that aspect?

RootViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "ChildViewController.h"

@interface RootViewController : UIViewController

@property(nonatomic,strong) IBOutlet ChildViewController *level2ViewController1;
@property(nonatomic,strong) IBOutlet ChildViewController *level2ViewController2;
@property(nonatomic,strong) IBOutlet ChildViewController *level2ViewController3;
@property(nonatomic,strong) IBOutlet ChildViewController *level2ViewController4;
@property(nonatomic,strong) IBOutlet ChildViewController *level2ViewController5;
@property(nonatomic,strong) IBOutlet ChildViewController *level2ViewController6;
@property(nonatomic,strong) IBOutlet ChildViewController *level2ViewController7;
@property(nonatomic,strong) IBOutlet ChildViewController *level2ViewController8;
@property(nonatomic,strong) IBOutlet ChildViewController *level2ViewController9;
@property(nonatomic,strong) IBOutlet ChildViewController *level2ViewController10;

-(IBAction)showChild1Action:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)showChild2Action:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)showChild3Action:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)showChild4Action:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)showChild5Action:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)showChild6Action:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)showChild7Action:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)showChild8Action:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)showChild9Action:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)showChild10Action:(id)sender;

@end
```

RootViewController.m

```
#import "RootViewController.h"

@interface RootViewController ()

@end

@implementation RootViewController

@synthesize level2ViewController1;
@synthesize level2ViewController2;
@synthesize level2ViewController3;
@synthesize level2ViewController4;
@synthesize level2ViewController5;
@synthesize level2ViewController6;
@synthesize level2ViewController7;
@synthesize level2ViewController8;
@synthesize level2ViewController9;
@synthesize level2ViewController10;


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
}

-(IBAction)showChild1Action:(id)sender{
    self.level2ViewController1.index=0;
    [self presentModalViewController:self.level2ViewController1 animated:true];
}
-(IBAction)showChild2Action:(id)sender{
    self.level2ViewController2.index=1;
    [self presentModalViewController:self.level2ViewController2 animated:true];
}
-(IBAction)showChild3Action:(id)sender{
    self.level2ViewController3.index=2;
    [self presentModalViewController:self.level2ViewController3 animated:true];
}
-(IBAction)showChild4Action:(id)sender{
    self.level2ViewController4.index=3;
    [self presentModalViewController:self.level2ViewController4 animated:true];
}
-(IBAction)showChild5Action:(id)sender{
    self.level2ViewController5.index=4;
    [self presentModalViewController:self.level2ViewController5 animated:true];
}
-(IBAction)showChild6Action:(id)sender{
    self.level2ViewController6.index=5;
    [self presentModalViewController:self.level2ViewController6 animated:true];
}
-(IBAction)showChild7Action:(id)sender{
    self.level2ViewController7.index=6;
    [self presentModalViewController:self.level2ViewController7 animated:true];
}
-(IBAction)showChild8Action:(id)sender{
    self.level2ViewController8.index=7;
    [self presentModalViewController:self.level2ViewController8 animated:true];
}
-(IBAction)showChild9Action:(id)sender{
    self.level2ViewController9.index=8;
    [self presentModalViewController:self.level2ViewController9 animated:true];
}
-(IBAction)showChild10Action:(id)sender{
    self.level2ViewController10.index=9;
    [self presentModalViewController:self.level2ViewController10 animated:true];
}

@end
```

ChildViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ChildViewController : UIViewController

@property(nonatomic,weak) IBOutlet UIImageView *image1;

@property NSInteger index;

-(IBAction)closeAction:(id)sender;

@end
```

ChildViewController.m

```
#import "ChildViewController.h"

@interface ChildViewController ()

@end

@implementation ChildViewController

@synthesize image1;
@synthesize index;


- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
    if(self.index==0)
        [self.image1 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"IMG1.JPG"]];
    if(self.index==1)
        [self.image1 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"IMG2.JPG"]];
    if(self.index==2)
        [self.image1 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"IMG3.JPG"]];
    if(self.index==3)
        [self.image1 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"IMG4.JPG"]];
    if(self.index==4)
        [self.image1 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"IMG5.JPG"]];
    if(self.index==5)
        [self.image1 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"IMG6.JPG"]];
    if(self.index==6)
        [self.image1 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"IMG7.JPG"]];
    if(self.index==7)
        [self.image1 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"IMG8.JPG"]];
    if(self.index==8)
        [self.image1 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"IMG9.JPG"]];
    if(self.index==9)
        [self.image1 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"IMG10.JPG"]];

}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}

-(IBAction)closeAction:(id)sender{
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:true];
}
```

When using Instruments I get these observations:

- The memory allocation instrument is showing what I would expect to see: total allocation that goes up when child view controller is presented, goes down when child view is dismissed
  [image: This is after showing then dismissing 3 child view controllers]
- However the activity indicator is telling a different story, with real memory increasing with every presentModalViewController, and never decreasing when dismissing them

[image: This is also after showing/dismissing 3 child view controllers]

Comment: Try using UIImage's `initWithContentsOfFile:` method instead of `imageNamed:`

Comment: @Rickay same results with initWithContentsOfFile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer I eventually got back from Apple:

> Your "large resources" happen to be images that you've loaded cached
>   via +imageNamed:. Because they are loaded cached, they are exempted
>   from the automatic cleanup. Generally only content generated via
>   -drawRect: or by Core Animation is automatically released here. Because your views continue to exist, they continue to hold a
>   reference to these cached images, and we can't purge them on memory
>   warning either

Looks like cached resource isn't part of the automatic cleanup mentioned in the doc, and those resources only get deallocated when they stop being referenced.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you have a leak somewhere. Even if the system isn't releasing those views, memory use should max out after you've presented all 10 child controllers. If memory use grows without bound, your child controllers are probably giving up their views (and so creating new ones each time they're presented), but the views aren't being deallocated -- classic symptom of an over-retain situation. Try cutting the number of child controllers down to two and see if the same thing eventually happens. Or, use Instruments to look for a leak.

**Update:** `-[UIImage imageNamed]` has a reputation for never releasing the images it loads -- that may be the reason for your memory growth. Try loading the images using a different method, or not at all (since they're not really important to the experiment).

Comment: I may not have been clear. The memory grows only when calling presentModalViewController. The memory does NOT grow if I present the same child view controller again and again (since it's already loaded the first time I present it). My question is about my expectations that it would be unloaded when being dismissed, based on my understanding of what's new in iOS6

Comment: I edited my question with pretty much the entire code. The xibs have the various objects corresponding to the outlets.

Comment: I understand what you're saying, but the behavior you describe is obviously inconsistent with the documented behavior. Updated my answer with a possible explanation.

Comment: It is inconsistent with my understanding of the doc, hence the question. Could you suggest another method than UIImage imageNamed to load an image? I used that example because 1)UIImage is the perfect exemple of what takes memory in a UIView hierarchy, the experiment would be less interesting with just a few UIButton elements  2)the sample project is in relation to what I have observed in a larger project where I need to load background graphics, etc.. so if the problem is related to UIImage, then we can figure that problem instead, what would I modify to obtain the desired behavior?

Comment: tried initWithContentsOfFile instead of imageNamed -> same results

Comment: Use Instruments to look at the memory that's building up. What are those objects?

Comment: See my updated question with screenshots, I get different results from activity monitor and allocations instruments, I am not sure what to conclude

Comment: @Caleb That `imageNamed:` bug has been fixed since iOS 3.0. Only apps compiled with the 2.x SDK will retain the bug for backwards compatibility.

Comment: @JustSid Thanks for that -- I wasn't sure whether it had been fixed or not, which I why I only said 'reputation'. Nevertheless, `-imageNamed:` still caches images, so it could have accounted for the memory growth that the OP is seeing, and the crash could have been due to something else entirely.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `imageNamed:` use `initWithContentsOfFile`.

For example:

```
__weak NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"image" ofType:@"png"];
self.imageView.image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
```

Because `alloc` method is being used, GC is marking this object. You can even mark the  `filePath` string for GC cleanup.